# Вывод массива на график

Tags: rust

Решил начать изучение языка `Rust`. Сделал простой код

```
use std::f32::consts::PI;

fn main() {
    let mut arr = [0.; 1800];
    let d = [2.0268, 1.4332, 1.1702, 1.0134, 0.9064, 0.8275];
    let it = [100, 19, 30, 9, 12, 6];

    let lambda = 1.5406;

    for i in 0..6 {
        let rad = 1. * lambda / (2. * d[i]);
        if rad < 1. {
            let thet = rad * 180. / PI * 10.;
            let angl = 2 * (thet as i32);
            arr[angl as usize] = it[i] as f64;
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь вопрос: как вывести на график полученный массив `arr`?

Comment: Простой ответ - никак. Вам для начала нужно решить в каком виде будет этот график. Никаких встроенных инструментов для построения графиков в языке не предусмотрено. Можно например записать данные в файл и построить в matlab.

Comment: Так я и не собираюсь использовать встроенные инструменты языка. Нашел в интернете crate "plotters", вроде умеет показывать график по массиву. Однако, там он иногда ругается на типы данных (во многих местах требует, чтобы массив был целочисленным).

Comment: Там вроде достаточно простой пример. Лучше дополните свой вопрос кодом и ошибкой у plotters, на это будет понятно как отвечать. А то у вас сейчас слишком расплывчатый вопрос.